# How to fix Resolving to directories is not possible with the exports field when deploy Nextjs at Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I tried to deploy NextJS at vercel then failed, but success build when i try at my local.

I have this logs

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Resolving to directories is not possible with the exports field (request was ./)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I once faced a similar issue, and it was due to one of my import files' name cases. Git normally doesn't recognize the case change in the file name, for example, `Name.js` and `name.js`; this change will not trigger a git change.

On the other hand Vercels file system is case-sensitive, so the same thing that is working locally may give a module-not-found error in Vercel deployment.

To solve this, you can either find out the inconsistent file name and fix it or you can run this git command to disable the ignorecase functionality:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

Hopefully, this answer will be helpful to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just resolved my problem with another case

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue. The problem is I accidentally import component and i write the path with '/' at the end.

Just remove it and VOILA!

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).